# Docker build just freezes?

Tags: docker

```
docker build -t {name}/ruby-test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 13.23 MB
Step 0 : FROM ruby:2.2.2
```

When I run the docker build command above it gets as far as you see.. and never continues.  Not sure why or what to do about it.  Thoughts?

Comment: From time to time, I get frozen builds, I have to reboot my docker-machine vm if that's what you're using.

Comment: How long did you wait for it? is ruby:2.2.2 in "docker images"

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just had to add `.git` to my `.dockerignore` file and then it flew along.

Comment: That would result in a different freeze, before the build context line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old and unresolved Docker bug. A workaround that works most of the time is to enclose the failing step with a random file creation/removal process.

```
RUN touch `echo random.$RANDOM`.txt
<YOUR FAILING STEP>
RUN rm random.*.txt;
```

Comment: but this increases the image size unnecessary